# Каким образом можно перегрузить (overload) оператор вычитания?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Разбираюсь с Java, появилась гора вопросов, помогите с вопросами.
Java это объектно-ориентированная «надстройка» над языком C или самостоятельный обьектно-ориентированный язык? Я бы сказал что это самостоятельный язык... Хотя может и надстройка некая( Сомневаюсь...

И вот вопрос(из закрепления материала):
Каким образом можно перегрузить (overload) оператор вычитания:

1. Ничего из перечисленного
2. С помощью модификатора оverload
3. С помощью аннотации [@Overload](/users/8116/overloader)
4. Как и обычный метод

Comment: Насчет второго вопроса, явно 2), но при чем тут @ в 4-м?

Comment: @Alerr
в жаве есть перегрузка методов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Java - более чем самостоятельный язык, практически никакого отношения к Си не имеющий
2. Насколько знаю, перегрузки операторов в Java нет (не стоит ее путать с перегрузкой и переопределением методов)

Answer (score 3):

Язык программирования Java не позволяет перегружать оператор.

Comment: Какие методы, определены в интерфейсе Serializable:
1) readExternal и writeExternal

2) serialize и deserialize

3) readObject и writeObject
?  И где найти этот интерфейс?

Comment: Читайте фирменную документацию -- [Interface Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: на сколько я понял, со своим знанием английского: writeObject и readObject. Верно?

Comment: Хотя на сайте нашел методы: writeExternal и readExt....

Answer (score 3):

[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr), Java это полностью самостоятельный язык. Просто у многих языков (в т.ч. и Си) синтаксис базовых управляющих конструкций очень похож.

Перегрузить (переопределить) оператор (`+, -, ++, >` ....) в Java нельзя. А вот методы можно [и переопределять и перегружать](http://ithq.ru/index.php/article/view/peregruzka-overload-i-pereopredelenie-override-metodov-v-java).